# Set-acl not working in powershell 3.0

Tags: powershell

I have a new starter script which works fine in Powershell 2.0 but I have had to upgrade to Powershell 3.0 to get some SQL stuff working. However this breaks all the parts of my script that use Set-Acl. Using powershell 2.0 is not an option. Has anyone found a way around this:
My code:

```
#Set home directory permissions
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
$acl = Get-Acl $newfolder
$accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$username", "FullControl", $inherit, $propagation, "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
set-acl -aclobject $acl $newfolder
write-host permissions set

#Set home folder owner
$acl = Get-Acl $newfolder;
$domain = "mydomain" 
$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$domain\$username");
$acl.SetOwner($sid);
Set-Acl $newfolder $acl; 
write-host owner set
```

Comment: In what way is Set-Acl broken in V3?  What error are you seeing on V3?

Comment: I'm not able to repro in PS 3.0. I copied your code and ran it and it worked with no errors. (PS version 3.0, CLR 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the parameters with a colon.

Example:

Before:`set-acl -aclobject $acl $newfolder`

After:`set-acl -aclobject:$acl -Path:$newfolder`

**Note:**
Use the full path of $newfolder.

```
set-acl -aclobject:$acl -path:$newfolder.FullName
```

Explanation: Powershell cmdlets have ordered binding and positioning, using a colon ensures that your value is assigned to the correct parameter, no matter what order or type of object. The `.FullName` property will prevent a `SetSecurityDescriptor` error.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Something must have changed in Powershell 3.0. The error I get is set-acl : Cannot set the ACL because the method that it needs to invoke, SetSecurityDescriptor, does not exist.

Comment: A workaround would be to explicitly call Powershell Version 2: `powershell -version 2.0 script.sql` or something similar (found on http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/303987-powershell-set-acl-not-working)

Comment: Using powershell 2.0 is not an option as the SQL commands I run don't work in Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this as I did...

I was getting the following error:

> Set-Acl : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity' because it does not exist.

I had to actually specify the Path and AclObject parameters:

```
Set-Acl -Path C:\mydir -AclObject $acl
```